# Why getinfo() and listchannels() inactive channel count differs?

Tags: python, core-lightning

I have strange results comparing node information outputs between getinfo() and listchannels() calls. Maybe someone has thoughts what is wrong (with my trivial code or with c-lightning itself):

```
chans = lnd.listchannels(source=mychan)['channels']
for chan in chans:
    if chan['active'] == False:
        total_inactive += 1
        print('inactive chan with node: ' + chan['destination'])
    else:
        total_active += 1

print('my inactive chans: ' + str(total_inactive))
print('my active chans: ' + str(total_active))
```

gives me:

```
my inactive chans: 2 
my active chans: 23
```

But, lightning-cli getinfo gives:

```
"num_active_channels": 25,
"num_inactive_channels": 5,
```

Comment: waited for 10+ hours.. now things become even more strange. while upgrading the node there was an event when i launched backuped node copy, so many of my channels closed for some reason (perhaps channels closed because other nodes refused old data). anyway, tried again to launch script and getinfo:

getinfo:
"num_active_channels" : 5,
"num_inactive_channels" : 25

while script output:
my inactive chans: 3
my active chans: 2

wierd.. but i think this is due to slow state refreshing in LN. will close manually 'inactive' channels i see on cli and then ill reply about results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you have (or rather had them at the time you ran the commands) 6 channels that were funded, but not yet announced. This is most likely why your node sees them (`getinfo`) but `gossipd` doesn't yet (`listchannels`) since they haven't been announced just yet.

Comment: Nvm previous comment its misleading and has nothing to do with question. But should i use listchannels() to get more descriptive info about inactive channels mentioned in getinfo()?

Comment: They are two separate sources of information, so we'd need to reconcile the differences. Might be worth doing at some point, but likely a low priority task currently.

Answer (score 0):

as Rene Pickhardt pointed me:

> without context I studiert you installed the pylifhtning client via
>   pip and upgraded you lightning node later so that the APIs have
>   different versions. But that is only a wild guess for a common error

Comment: To my defense when I was approached with the question I only knew that the output differed. I did not know how and pointed also out that my replay was a rough / blind guess

Comment: anyway, this was a good point. i really had different versions of api and cli and your suggestion makes sense to prevent futher glitches!

Comment: Yeah but as Cdecker wrote you make a different api call in your python script in comparison to the cli call

Comment: Emmm.. i didnt get it first, i understood thad different software subprocesses are acting in different ways, but soon or late ill get same result. In general i would like exactly to compare the data which gives listfunds and getinfo. I used api simply to not count inactive channels manually, but the idea was to found detailed information about inactive channels that getinfo() outputs. I thought listchannels() is exactly what i need for this

Comment: My question title is misleading, it should be: why listfunds() and getinfo() shows me different stats. Regardless of api/cli